# How do I link one sensor to an asynchronous loop that runs as long as the sensor input is high, and then repeat the same process with another sensor?

Tags: asynchronous, python-asyncio, esp8266, micropython

I'm at my wit's end here.  I'm using 2 different sensors.  When the first sensor is triggered, I want to blink a yellow LED one time per second.  When the second sensor is triggered, I want to blink a red LED two times per second.  I am able to do this one at a time, which is ok, but I cannot make the process repeat (as in, I will trigger the first sensor and the yellow LED pattern will play, but triggering that sensor again has no effect.  I cannot trigger the other sensor either unless I close the program and restart.  Please note the following code is in Micropython on an ESP8266-12E.

```
import uasyncio as asyncio
import machine
import time
import os

# Yellow LED: Pin 15
Y_LED = machine.PWM(machine.Pin(15))
Y_LED.freq(300)

# Red LED: Pin 2
R_LED = machine.PWM(machine.Pin(2))
R_LED.freq(300)

H2_1 = machine.Pin(9, machine.Pin.IN, machine.Pin.PULL_UP)

H2_2 = machine.Pin(4, machine.Pin.IN, machine.Pin.PULL_UP)

async def FlashRed():
  for i in range (20):
    R_LED.duty(1023)
    await asyncio.sleep(0.5)
    R_LED.duty(0)
    await asyncio.sleep(0.5)

async def FlashYellow():
  for i in range (10):
    Y_LED.duty(1023)
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    Y_LED.duty(0)
    await asyncio.sleep(1)    

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

def Check_Button():
  while True:
    if H2_1.value():
      loop.create_task(FlashRed())
      loop.run_forever()
    if H2_2.value():
      loop.create_task(FlashYellow())
      loop.run_forever()
    time.sleep(0.1)

while True:
    Check_Button()
```

I would like for the board to display a flashing red LED when pin 9 is high, and then display that flashing red LED until pin 9 is low.

I would also like the board to display a flashing yellow LED when pin 4 is high, and likewise, display that flashing yellow LED until pin 4 is low.

I would like to be able to trigger both the pin 9 red pattern and the pin 4 yellow LED pattern simultaneously or independently.

Currently, I can only do one or the other.  The board waits for an input from either pin 9 or 4, which is great.  When pin 9 goes high, the board correctly displays the red flashing LED pattern.  The pattern repeats 10 times, which is great.  But then, after the pattern finishes, I cannot initiate it again, nor can I initiate the yellow flashing LED pattern.  If I start with the yellow pattern, I cannot restart the yellow pattern and I cannot start the red pattern.  I have to quit the script and start again.

Looping Check_Button() isn't working for me.

Any help at all would be much appreciated.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to call `run_forever` if you have more things to do, because it will literally run the loop forever, even after the created tasks finish.

I cannot test this, but you can try something like this:

```
async def Check_Button():
    while True:
        if H2_1.value():
            loop.create_task(FlashRed())
        if H2_2.value():
            loop.create_task(FlashYellow())
        await asyncio.sleep(0.1)

loop.run_until_complete(Check_Button())
```

Comment: Thank you :). That was kind of you to help out.